# Installed wrong OS need to install 32 bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

Like the title states I installed the 64 bit which was the wrong one to install. How do I go back and install the 32-bit version instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should do a full install of a 32 bit cd or DVD.

Go here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Under the tick box **"Choose your flavor"** make sure you choose 32 bit.

After download, just install it like you did before, overwriting the partitions you have choosed for the 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-install, there is no way to convert a 64 bit install to a 32 bit install.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change it because you're having trouble with the 64-bit OS on your 32-bit architecture you have to download the correct 32-bit image from ubuntu.com and reinstall the Operating System.